# Javascript 2d array initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am plotting a data set using javascript.flot library and jquery. The libraary require to pass a [[x1,y1], [x2, y2], [x3, y3]] pairs to the plot function. I used the following code to initialize the array d2 for plot:

```
                    var d2=[];
                     for(var i=0; i<9; i++) {
                         d2.push([myx[i], myy[i]]);
                     }
```

where myx and myy are 1d arrays
 of x and y values resp.

This doesnot work. i m unable to troubleshoot. What is wrong with my code or if it is a browser problem.

Comment: can you prepare a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) please?

Answer (score 0):

### Create Two Dimensional Array in Javascript:

```
var iMax = 20;
var jMax = 10;
var f = new Array();

for (i=0;i<iMax;i++) {
    f[i]=new Array();
    for (j=0;j<jMax;j++) {
        f[i][j]=0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made an example with jquery plot in jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/n7w2d/

```
$(function() {
  var myx = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
  var myy = [ 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10];
  // THIS IS YOUR CODE
  var d2=[];
  for(var i=0; i<9; i++) {
    d2.push([myx[i], myy[i]]);
  }
  // END OF YOUR CODE
  $.plot("#placeholder", [ d2 ]);
});
```

1. A HTML #placeholder
2. A CSS rule to add a height to the div.
3. Made up some myx, myy data

Comment: Also, if you get your myx, myy from external source, you need to make sure they are javascript Number and not string in some plotting library. Using  d2.push([+myx[i], +myy[i]])  should convert "1" (string) to 1 (number)

Comment: we may not wish (or need) to include a 90kb jquery file in any problem smarty.